# How do I compare user input to a preset character to see if they are the same?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm trying to figure out a way to properly take a string that I am getting from the user as input, and compare it to a specific character to see if they are the same.

I've tried comparing my user input to my preset string, but to no avail. You can see what I did in my code:

```
.data
userInput:      .space      4
pieceMessage:   .asciiz "\nSelect a piece (X/O): "
pieceX:     .asciiz "x"
.text

main:

    jal selectPiece

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

    selectPiece:
#Display prompt
li      $v0, 4
la      $a0, pieceMessage
syscall

#Enter your desired piece
move    $a0,$t2
li  $v0, 8
la  $a0, userInput
li  $a1, 10
syscall

#Compare
la  $s2, pieceX
move    $t2, $s2
la  $s3, userInput
move    $t3, $s3
bne $t2,$t3,selectPiece

jr $ra
```

The expected result is that when the user enters exactly "x", they should be able to continue, but if they enter anything else, it will call the selectPiece function again to ask them again. However, even when I enter exactly "x", it still doesn't think they are the same. I'm not quite sure what parts I'm missing, because if I replace pieceX with another userInput, it gives me the expected result, so I know it's storing them properly, but the comparison never seems to succeed if I compare userInput to pieceX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your instruction

`bne $t2,$t3,selectPiece`

compares `$t2` and `$t3` which are addresses of strings `userInput` and `pieceX``and are obviously always different.

What you want is to compare what these addresses point to. There should some kind of load before the comparison.

```
#Compare
la     $s2, pieceX
lb     $t2, ($s2)  ; mem[$s2] -> $t2
la     $s3, userInput
lb     $t3, ($s3)  ; mem[$s3] -> $t3
bne    $t2,$t3,selectPiece
```